# .NET MAUI Dependency Injection in platform specific code

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

Is there any way to inject services in platform specific code, for example in `MainActivity.cs`? I think Xamarin used `DependencyService` for this.
Also is it possible to inject them into background `Services` and `Broadcast Receivers`?

What I tried to do at the moment is newing them up but I wonder if there is a better solution at the moment. For what I understand, the DI container in platform specific code is not the same as the main one that you use in `MauiProgram.cs`, I've seen example where they implement one from scratch.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code

Comment: @Jason this seems usefull to consume platform specific services in the shared part of the project. I need to inject my custom services in main activity ecc. Am i missing something?

Comment: [Dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I'm not sure that would be usefull since the template for the startup of the app is very different, every platform has its own.

Comment: What is it you want to inject? And where do you hope to inject it from? And can you point to an example, on Android or iOS, in any language, similar to what you have in mind? Generally, each OS has its own startup process, that AFAIK cannot be altered. During that startup, you startup services, that can be used elsewhere in code. Until the app starts, there is nowhere to run code, to perform an injection. Therefore, the services to be injected are created in the startup code. DI is done to code that runs later - not to the startup process itself.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve check the [Local notifications in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications) docs.
Go down to "Handle incoming notifications on Android" section. In the code example there is a line like this `DependencyService.Get<INotificationManager>().ReceiveNotification(title, message);`. So in Xamarin the dependency service would get you a service in the MainActivity.cs class. I want to do something similar in Maui.
My services live in a folder on the root of the project.

Comment: Yes, I know. You've missed the point. Yes, you can do what that shows. Either using DependencyService like XF, or using .Net 6's newer mechanism. BUT to use that, you have to have RUN CODE EARLIER to create the service. In that example, when the app started, the platform-specific startup code created the service to be used. THE PROBLEM IS, you've asked how to inject INTO the app's platform-specific startup code. BY DEFINITION, that is the FIRST code to run. So I'll ask again: WHAT do you want to inject, and WHERE are you hoping to inject it from??

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve so from what i've understand about your comment, basically the dependencyService can retrieve that service because in the `OnCreate` method there is a dependencyService registration. If this is the case I don't really need to inject from outside on this method, i just want my service available in the mainActivity.cs without doing new MyService(); and storing it to a variable. Do you actually know how to use dependencyService or the .Net 6 mechanism in Maui? There is no `CreateHostBuilder` in `MainApplication.cs` (the entry point class for android in maui)

Comment: Ok i think i might figured it out with the dependencyService. Would be great to know how to use the .net6 version

Comment: Hmm. Since .net 6 is advertised to run on ios and android, I assumed you could use DI there. But they seem to be missing [.NET Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host). WIthout a `Host`, there's no way DI could be automatically injected into constructors.

Answer (score 9):

I found this on [Jame Montemagno's Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/c/JamesMontemagno).  I think this is what you are looking for.  The video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xx1mve2AQr4).

```
public static class ServiceHelper {

public static T GetService<T>() => Current.GetService<T>();

public static IServiceProvider Current =>
#if WINDOWS10_0_17763_0_OR_GREATER
    MauiWinUIApplication.Current.Services;
#elif ANDROID
    MauiApplication.Current.Services;
#elif IOS || MACCATALYST
    MauiUIApplicationDelegate.Current.Services;
#else
    null;
#endif }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @Blush worked for me.
I changed it a little bit. Instead of passing an action I just pass a collection of plattform specific services and add those too.

```cs
// android implementation
protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddSingleton<ITestService, TestService>();

    return MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp(services);
}

// shared app
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp(IServiceCollection platformServices)
{
     var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

     // register shared services
     builder.Services.AddTransient<SharedService>();

     // register platform specific services
     foreach (var service in platformSpecificServices)
     {
         builder.Services.Add(service);
     }

     return builder.Build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to say

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp(Action<MauiAppBuilder> registerPlatformSpecificServices)
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>();
    registerPlatformSpecificServices?.Invoke(builder);

    return builder.Build();
}
```

and when you run the application from the platform specific code, send there a configurator function like

```
public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownership)
    : base(handle, ownership)
{
}

protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp(RegisterServices);

private static void RegisterServices(MauiAppBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ISmsProvider, SmsProvider>();
}
```